# iSeries COBOL - TALLYING BEFORE/AFTER

Tags: ibm-midrange, cobol

i have a field that have some tag inside
and I must extract the values between this tags.
String example:

```
MSG="HERE IS THE TAGS /33=10000/34=36363/35=22222"
```

So I must extract for example the value between "/33=" and "/34="... in this case 10000
In my cobol source I can have the first because it count all chars before "/33=":

```
INSPECT MSG TALLYING COUNT1 FOR CHARACTERS BEFORE "/33="
ADD 5 TO COUNT1
```

But I don't understand why is not work for the second the should give me nr. of chars I must estract:

```
INSPECT MSG TALLYING COUNT2 FOR CHARACTERS AFTER "/33=" BEFORE "/"
```

The COUNT2 give me 0

Anybody can help me please ?
Thanks in advance
Denis

Comment: Did you try INSPECT MSG TALLYING COUNT2 FOR CHARACTERS AFTER "/33=" BEFORE "/34"?

Comment: You might find it easier to use `UNSTRING MSG DELIMITED '/'...`

Comment: Yes I try a lot of variants for an hour... the I have use a classic PERFORM UNTIL in order to find the next "/" after the tag... 5 minute I have finish... Thanks a lot all  :-)

Comment: @Denis if you have a working solution please answer your own question and accept it (--> Q+A style); if you know the reason why your original approach did not work it would be good to include it in the answer.

Comment: No... I have not yet understand why it's not work. So my answer can not be the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use PERFORM UNTIL, where you could use INSPECT TALLYING to know the position of the slash. It would be like to ask for the index in a string.

All of it supposing you are needing it with variable length, otherwise to use a fixed structure is the best.

If I understood what you need, here it is:

```
WORKING STORAGE.
  01   TAB-OF-PARSED-INFO OCCURS 1 TO *[the max number of fields that you estimate]*
                         DEPENDING ON WS-I.  ---> this can be omitted with fixed occurs
       05 TAB-ITS-TAG        PIC X(04).
       05 TAB-WHAT-YOU-NEED  PIC X(*[the max size between slashes]*).
  01   WS-YOUR-STRING  PIC X(*[the max total size]*).
  01   WS-COUNTERS.
       05   WS-I            PIC 9(06).
       05   WS-COUNTER      PIC 9(06).
       05   WS-INDEX        PIC 9(06).
  01   WS-WHAT-SEPARATES    PIC X(01) VALUE '/'.
  01   WS-TIME-FLAG         PIC 9(01) VALUE 0.
       88  WS-FIRST-TIME              VALUE 0.
       88  WS-AFTER-TIME              VALUE 1.
...
  PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       
       INITIALIZE WS-COUNTERS

       INSPECT WS-YOUR-STRING 
       TALLYING WS-COUNTER FOR ALL WS-WHAT-SEPARATES

       PERFORM 1234-PARSING-SLASHES
          THRU 1234-PARSING-SLASHES-EXIT
         UNTIL WS-I >= WS-COUNTER
       ADD  1              TO WS-I
       MOVE WS-YOUR-STRING TO TAB-WHAT-YOU-NEED(WS-I)
       .
  1234-PARSING-SLASHES.
       MOVE ZEROES        TO WS-INDEX
       INSPECT WS-YOUR-STRING
       TALLYING WS-INDEX FOR ALL CHARACTERS BEFORE WS-WHAT-SEPARATES
       ADD  1             TO WS-I
       IF WS-FIRST-TIME THEN
          MOVE 'N/A'                      TO TAB-TAG(WS-I)
          MOVE WS-YOUR-STRING(1:WS-INDEX) TO TAB-WHAT-YOU-NEED(WS-I)
          SET WS-AFTER-TIME               TO TRUE
       ELSE
          MOVE WS-YOUR-STRING(1:3)        TO TAB-TAG(WS-I)
          MOVE WS-YOUR-STRING(4:WS-INDEX) TO TAB-WHAT-YOU-NEED(WS-I)
       END-IF
          
*    We adding 2 because WS-INDEX is the last non slash character. 
*    WS-INDEX + 1 is the slash
       ADD 2                              TO WS-INDEX
     
       COMPUTE WS-LEN      = LENGTH OF WS-YOUR-STRING
       MOVE WS-YOUR-STRING(WS-INDEX:WS-LEN) 
                                       TO WS-YOUR-STRING
      .
  1234-PARSING-SLASHES-EXIT.
  EXIT.
```

---

**INPUT:**

```
WS-YOUR-STRING="HERE IS THE TAGS /33=10000/34=36363/35=22222"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
WS-I                  = 01
TAB-TAG(01)           = N/A
TAB-WHAT-YOU-NEED(01) = HERE IS THE TAG 

WS-I                  = 02
WS-YOUR-STRING        = 33=10000/34=36363/35=22222
TAB-TAG(02)           = 33=
TAB-WHAT-YOU-NEED(02) = 10000

WS-I                  = 03
WS-YOUR-STRING        = 34=36363/35=22222
TAB-TAG(03)           = 34=
TAB-WHAT-YOU-NEED(03) = 36363

WS-I                  = 04
WS-YOUR-STRING        = 35=22222
TAB-TAG(04)           = 35=
TAB-WHAT-YOU-NEED(04) = 22222
```

If you find any mistake, please, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The INSPECT statement does not work because the "BEFORE '/'" is locating the first slash which is the one in "/33=" there for counting 0.